# My app runs smooth until yesterday but after android studio update it gives error

Tags: java, android

Error on 
inconvertible types cannot cast android.view.view to android.support.design.widget.navigationview

Comment: Could you please elaborate your post more...

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to assign two different object with the same name (view) but from different packages. Try check the imported packages on the head of the file.
If you see `android.support.design.widget.navigationview` remove it, go to where the IDE throws the error and import the correct package.
I'm assuming you need to use `android.view.view`. Otherwise remove `android.view.view` and reimport the correct pachage.